# convergence in measure does not imply weak convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Suppose $\sup_n\|f_n\|_1<\infty$ and $f_n\rightarrow f$ a.e.. However it is not necessary that $f_n\rightarrow f$ weakly in $L^1$.

Can someone raise an example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $f_n$ might even not belong to $L_1.$

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. Now $f_n\in L^1$.

Comment: Hi, Beck. Welcome to Math.Stackexchange. Could you edit to include where you came across this problem and what you've tried to solve it? Generally speaking, the community is much more receptive to questions that include those two pieces of information. Thanks!

Comment: The title asks a somewhat different question than the body of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try $f_n = n \, \chi_{(0,1/n)}$. The key to weak convergence in $L^1$ is uniform integrability. This does not hold for the above $f_n$.